# numpy: array of arrays multiplied with array of integers equal array

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a Pythonic way to calculate the array `z` without using the loop?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [6, 7, 8]])
y = np.array([5, 8])
z = np.array([x[i] * y[i] for i in range(0, len(x))])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
x * np.expand_dims(y, 1)
```

The multiplication will broadcast the result of the `expand_dims` (shape 2×1) as needed when multiplying by `x` (shape 2×3).

Result:

```
array([[ 5, 10, 15],
       [48, 56, 64]])
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need proper dim for `y` (shape `2,1`) to be multiply with `x` (shape `2,3`),
Here some other ways to add single extra dim to `y`

```
x * y[:, None]
array([[ 5, 10, 15],
       [48, 56, 64]])

x * y[:, np.newaxis]
array([[ 5, 10, 15],
       [48, 56, 64]])
```